# Laravel 5.8 Creating default object from empty value

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

When I try to update a record, I get an ErrorException "Creating default object from empty value" and points to my controller to $products->name = $request->input('name') line.

**ProductController**

```html
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $products = Product::find($id);

        $products->name = $request->input('name');
        $products->category_id = $request->select('category_id');
        $products->description = $request->input('description');
        $products->price_neto = $request->input('price_neto');
        $products->iva = $request->input('iva');
        $products->price_total = $request->input('price_total');

        $products->save();

        return response()->json([
            'error' => false,
            'products'  => $products,
        ], 200);
    }
```

I've searched but still can't find a solution.

**product.blade.php**

```html
@foreach ($product as $products)
<tr>
  <td>{{$products->id}}</td>
  <td>{{$products->name}}</td>
  <td>{{$products->category_id}}</td>
  <td>{{$products->description}}</td>
  <td>{{$products->price_neto}}</td>
  <td>{{$products->iva}}</td>
  <td>{{$products->price_total}}</td>

    <div class="form-button-action">
      <a onclick="event.preventDefault();editProductForm({{$products->id}});" href="#" class="edit open-modal" data-toggle="modal" value="{{$products->id}}"><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Editar">&#xE254;</i></a>
      <a onclick="event.preventDefault();deleteProductForm({{$products->id}});" href="#" class="delete" data-toggle="modal"><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Eliminar">&#xE872;</i></a>
    </div>
  </td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

**Routes**

These are my routes.

```html
Route::group(['prefix' => 'product'], function () {
        Route::get('/{id}', [
            'uses' => 'ProductController@show',
            'as'   => 'product.show',
        ]);

        Route::post('/', [
            'uses' => 'ProductController@store',
            'as'   => 'product.store',
        ]);

        Route::put('/{id}', [
            'uses' => 'ProductController@update',
            'as'   => 'product.update',
        ]);

        Route::delete('/{id}', [
            'uses' => 'ProductController@destroy',
            'as'   => 'product.destroy',
        ]);
    });
```

**Product.js**

And this is how my model works by pressing the edit button

```js
$("#btn-edit").click(function() {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        $.ajax({
            type: 'PUT',
            url: '/product/' + $("#frmEditProduct input[name=product_id]").val(),
            data: {
                name: $("#frmEditProduct input[name=name]").val(),
                category_id: $("#frmEditProduct select[name=category_id]").val(),
                description: $("#frmEditProduct input[name=description]").val(),
                price_neto: $("#frmEditProduct input[name=price_neto]").val(),
                iva: $("#frmEditProduct input[name=iva]").val(),
                price_total: $("#frmEditProduct input[name=price_total]").val(),
                image: $("#frmEditProduct input[name=image]").val(),
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#frmEditProduct').trigger("reset");
                $("#frmEditProduct .close").click();
                window.location.reload();
            },
            error: function(data) {
                var errors = $.parseJSON(data.responseText);
                $('#edit-product-errors').html('');
                $.each(errors.messages, function(key, value) {
                    $('#edit-product-errors').append('<li>' + value + '</li>');
                });
                $("#edit-error-bag").show();
            }
        });
    });
```

[An image on the project when I press Edit button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sst28.png)

```js
function editProductForm(product_id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/product/' + product_id,
        success: function(data) {
            $("#edit-error-bag").hide();
            $("#frmEditProduct input[name=name]").val(data.products.name);
            $("#frmEditProduct select[name=category_id]").val(data.products.category_id);
            $("#frmEditProduct input[name=description]").val(data.products.description);
            $("#frmEditProduct input[name=price_neto]").val(data.products.price_neto);
            $("#frmEditProduct input[name=iva]").val(data.products.iva);
            $("#frmEditProduct input[name=price_total]").val(data.products.price_total);
            $('#editProductModal').modal('show');
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `find($id)` will return null if not record finded with the given id. Check if the id is correct, also you can use `findOrFail($id)` to throw an exception if not record exists with that id

Comment: If you `dd($products)` what the results?

Comment: can you please share the migration

Comment: findOrFail($id) throw that 'No query results for model [App\Product] 0'. I use the same id to remove and it works. @porloscerrosΨ

Comment: Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->decimal('price_neto', 10, 2);
            $table->decimal('iva', 10, 2);
            $table->decimal('price_total', 10, 2);
            $table->timestamps();
        }); @SherazKhan

Comment: well, the message is pretty explicit, 'No query results for model [App\Product] 0'. Please, check the value of `$("#frmEditProduct input[name=product_id]").val()` in your ajax call, seems it's 0 (zero), which does not seem to correspond to the value of a primary key

Comment: Also, the ajax call is inside this function/event `$("#btn-edit").click(function() {...}`, but  does not seem to be related to the html you provide `<a onclick="event.preventDefault();editProductForm({{$products->id}});" href="#" class="edit open-modal" data-toggle="modal" value="{{$products->id}}"><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Editar">&#xE254;</i></a>`

Comment: It is related in the model on the frmEditProduct. The buttons look like this..          
  <div class="modal-footer">
  <input id="product_id" name="product_id" type="hidden" value="0">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-edit" type="button">Edit</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
  </div> @porloscerrosΨ and I use the same for Delete

Comment: you are hardcoding the value of the input[name=product_id] to 0. You would have to find the way to give it the value of the id of the product that is in edition. I don't know what the function `editProductForm` looks like to help you, but the problem seems to be there

Comment: This is the editProductForm that receive product_id. @porloscerrosΨ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing to assign the value of the product id to the input from where you get it to send the put request:

```
function editProductForm(product_id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/product/' + product_id,
        success: function(data) {
            $("#edit-error-bag").hide();

            $("#frmEditProduct input[name=product_id]").val(product_id) // <- assign the new value here!!!

            $("#frmEditProduct input[name=name]").val(data.products.name);
            $("#frmEditProduct select[name=category_id]").val(data.products.category_id);
            $("#frmEditProduct input[name=description]").val(data.products.description);
            $("#frmEditProduct input[name=price_neto]").val(data.products.price_neto);
            $("#frmEditProduct input[name=iva]").val(data.products.iva);
            $("#frmEditProduct input[name=price_total]").val(data.products.price_total);
            $('#editProductModal').modal('show');
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

then you can get it to build the ajax url for the put request:

```
$("#btn-edit").click(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: 'PUT',

        url: '/product/' + $("#frmEditProduct input[name=product_id]").val(),  // <- here you get the input value!!!

        data: {
            name: $("#frmEditProduct input[name=name]").val(),
            category_id: $("#frmEditProduct select[name=category_id]").val(),
            description: $("#frmEditProduct input[name=description]").val(),
            price_neto: $("#frmEditProduct input[name=price_neto]").val(),
            iva: $("#frmEditProduct input[name=iva]").val(),
            price_total: $("#frmEditProduct input[name=price_total]").val(),
            image: $("#frmEditProduct input[name=image]").val(),
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#frmEditProduct').trigger("reset");
            $("#frmEditProduct .close").click();
            window.location.reload();
        },
        error: function(data) {
            var errors = $.parseJSON(data.responseText);
            $('#edit-product-errors').html('');
            $.each(errors.messages, function(key, value) {
                $('#edit-product-errors').append('<li>' + value + '</li>');
            });
            $("#edit-error-bag").show();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes, that is what happened. I forgot my product_id and in my controller I just need to change the `$products->category_id = $request->select('category_id')` to  `$products->category_id = $request->input('category_id')`

Comment: great! glad to know you solved it. I'd missed that from the controller, yes you can use that syntax or just `$request->category_id`

Comment: Thank you very much friend I appreciate it. You saved me.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred when query returns a null value.

You can try something like this :

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $products = Product::find($id);

    if($products instanceof Product){
        $products->name = $request->input('name');
        $products->category_id = $request->select('category_id');
        $products->description = $request->input('description');
        $products->price_neto = $request->input('price_neto');
        $products->iva = $request->input('iva');
        $products->price_total = $request->input('price_total');

        $products->save();

        return response()->json([
            'error' => false,
            'products'  => $products,
        ], 200);
    }
    return response()->json([
        'error' => true,
        'message'  => 'Product not found.',
    ], 404);
}
```

Comment: Yes that throw the 'Product not found.'. @akshaypjoshi

Comment: Because product not available in your table with $id you are passing in controller.